# Why does the series $1/\sqrt k$ not converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}}$$

should converge because of the alternating series test (which I applied and showed, that the series converges).

The other quention was, if the series converges absolutely. Since we are proving $1/\sqrt{k}$ and the square root cannot deliver minus - the series should be absolutely convergent, too.

What I see in the solutions is, that the series does NOT converge absolutely. What am I doing false?

Comment: Not following.  The negative terms are produced by the numerator, namely $(-1)^{k+1}$.  Not from the square root term.

Comment: A series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely means $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ converges. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}}$ converges doesn't imply $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ converge.

Comment: Hint: $1/\sqrt{k} > 1 /k$, therefore $\sum_k 1/\sqrt{k} > \sum_k 1 /k$

Comment: Alright! Understang the issue now. But did I prove it correctly that the series converges (for the proof, I only used 1/sqrt(k)?

Comment: You didn't provide any details for your conditional convergence argument, so we can't tell if you did it correctly or not.

Answer (score 2):

A series $\sum a_k$ converges absolutely if the corresponding series $\sum|a_k|$ also converges. In your case, the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}}$$
certainly converges, but the series made from the absolute values of these terms, namely
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
does not. This is seen easily by the comparison test. For all $k\geq 1$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\geq\frac{1}{k},$$
but we know the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ diverges (it's the harmonic series). Thus, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ must also diverge.